# Rename table column name model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, field, rename

I have this problem.

I have to implement an application that read data from a PostgreSql db.
I can't modify the db, I can only read this.

There is a table that have some columns, but one of this is named "update".

When I try to read all the record from this table and print them into screen, the application tell me:

> "ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError in HomeController#index"
>
> "update is defined by ActiveRecord"

How  can I rename the column in the application/model? (I can't modify the db)
What's the better solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rails virtual attributes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
  end

  def full_name=(name)
    split = name.split(' ', 2)
    self.first_name = split.first
    self.last_name = split.last
  end
end
```

then you can use full_name as a model attribute.